# Count animation issue using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I made the count animation feature using Javascript. I have coded something like the one below, but there is still a problem.

I have the following numbers such a `200`, `20.5`, `1500`. When the animation is running, the number `20.5` becomes `21`. I want that number to remain `20.5` and the other numbers to still `200` and `1500`.

Where is the missing or error that I've made?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.count').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#countAnimation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box-counter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countAnimation">
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">20.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you used `Math.ceil(...)`

Comment: and how should it be? @CuongLeNgoc

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.count').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(now % 1 > 0 ? now.toFixed(1) : now);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#countAnimation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box-counter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countAnimation">
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">20.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use your function `step` until `Math.ceil(now)` is bigger than your final number. Then you just insert the final number when the animation is done using the `complete` callback:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.count').each(function() {
    var countTo = Number($(this).text())

    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: countTo - 1
    }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        var ceil = Math.ceil(now)
        if (ceil < countTo) {
          $(this).text(ceil);
        }
      },
      complete: function() {
        $(this).text(countTo);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#countAnimation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box-counter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  color: #0f0f0f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countAnimation">
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">20.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-counter">
    <div class="count">1500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but like there was a pause waiting. waiting at 20, waiting for another number to finish and then to 20.5

Comment: Use `Counter: countTo - 1` and it feels better. I updated my answer.